# How to show cypress test result when running `nx affected --target=e2e`

Tags: cypress, nrwl-nx

I'd like to run my ci e2e test using `nx affected --target=e2e`, but I want to see the cypress test results in the terminal as they occur. `--verbose` doesn't achieve this.

**Is there a flag to show the test output?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank to the Nx team's support in their slack channel, I discovered the flag `--output-style=` which archives this with values `static`, `stream`, & `stream-without-prefixes`

Comment: Recommend using the nx console. Available flags show up in the gui

Comment: @AndrewAllen Is that possible for `affected` commands? how?

Comment: apologies, looking at my Nx console show only about half the available options documented here: https://nx.dev/packages/nx/documents/affected#output-style. There is an option to edit and add (pen icon) to "Common Nx Commands" so this may be helpful